# Как организовать хранение почты НЕ на сервере?

Tags: email, outlook, dovecot

Суть: есть корпоративная почта на 10 сотрудников, вся почта хранится на сервере хостинга, там же где и сайты лежат, организация почты через Maildir(ну там где папки cur, tmp), тарифный план: 5гб. Эти 5гб заполняются за пару месяцев, сайты занимают 20мб, все остальное почта, все сотрудники используют локальный клиент почты Outlook, протокол IMAP, постоянно покупать новые гигабайты не вариант. Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы вся почта хранилась на локальном комьютере каждого сотруджника а не на сервере ?

Comment: pop3 + в клиентах галка на Оставлять копии сообщений на сервере не более N дней.

Comment: В настройках почтового клиента отключить опцию хранить письма не сервере или включить опцию удалять письма с сервера, смотря какая имеется. Только бывает такое, что у пользователей с компьютеров самое важное пропадает. И где потом взять?